# Iframe to display google charts

Tags: css, iframe, position

I've got a MySQL database and have a few Google charts querying the data.

I'm looking for a way to display the charts in a neater way. I currently have each chart on a separate page, so I'm wondering if an Iframe is the way to go?

I'm hoping to click on a vertical list menu and see the different charts populate the Iframe.

**This works, but I have some problems:**

- placing the Iframe to the right of the menu at the top of the page,
- the menu's css also wont work,
- a new page also fires, when I click of the menu.

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
  <title>Graph Menu</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="./js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Graph navigation page</h1>
  <hr />
  <iframe frameborder="0" width="65%" height="800" style="float:centre" src="http://mysite" name="graphs" id="graphs">
  <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
  </iframe><br />


  <ul>
  <li><a href="http://mysite"target="graphs">Graph1</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://mysite"target="graphs">Graph2</a></li>
  </ul>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just use *float: right*

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="65%" height="800" style="float:right" src="http://mysite" name="graphs" id="graphs">
<p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe><br />
```

Comment: Thanks, I have played around with the position and size but i'm just not feelng it. Positioning seems a bit messy which is not helped by the style sheet menu not firing.